# How do I uninstall vscodium installed via nix-darwin?

Tags: nix, darwin, nix-darwin

I removed it from my darwin configuration file and rebuilt it.
It removes the `codium` binary from the path and removes the Application from the `/Applications/Nix Apps` folder.
But I know this isn't over because vscodium still shows up in Launchpad. And when I click it, it actually opens. Meaning, the binary is still there somewhere.

I found out that these are still present in the nix store:

```
/nix/store/4ghl639j3kayp4r6j888waiwf87fff5i-vscodium-1.82.2.23257
├── Applications
│   └── VSCodium.app
└── bin
    └── codium -> ../Applications/VSCodium.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/codium
```

I wish to remove this but I worry about blindly deleting the nix/store entry.

`nix store delete /nix/store/4ghl639j3kayp4r6j888waiwf87fff5i-vscodium-1.82.2.23257` does not work because this path is still used by nix somewhere.

`nix-store --query --roots /nix/store/4ghl639j3kayp4r6j888waiwf87fff5i-vscodium-1.82.2.23257` gives me:

```
/nix/var/nix/profiles/system-13-link -> /nix/store/xy8xn7p7d93d82az9k3bfdr1slfbzmk5-darwin-system-23.11pre527787.e12483116b3b+darwin4
/nix/var/nix/profiles/system-3-link -> /nix/store/931147anpckm0r7cprhc6p1j8lq9qqdr-darwin-system-23.11pre527787.e12483116b3b+darwin4
```

Can someone help me with cleaning this up?

Comment: Just because a package still exists in the store, it doesn't mean its in your profile. That being said, try the following :

`nix profile list | grep -iE vscodium` then `nix profile remove <packages>`.